# Dynamic permalinks when creating a post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I have a custom post type named houses. Inside my custom post type I have several custom fields which I created using ACF.

What I need to do is to change the permalink when I create a new post.

I would like to use the **code** and **title** fields to customize the permalink:

```
//code + post title
4563312-house-example-1
```

I'm developing a plugin which controls everything.

Is there a way to intermediate the creation of a post to update its permalink?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I found an answer related to wp_insert_post_data.

Using wp_insert_post_data, I couldn't get the custom field value, and to achieve that, I had to use another action, **save_post** instead.

```
function rci_custom_permalink($post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if($post->post_type !== 'houses') return;

  $code = get_field('code', $post_id);
  $post_name = sanitize_title($post->post_title);
  $permalink = $code . '-' . $post_name;

  // remove the action to not enter in a loop
  remove_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_permalink');

  // perform the update
  wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' => $permalink));

  // add the action again
  add_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_permalink');
} 

add_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_permalink');
```

PS: Since all these fields are required, I didn't need to check if they are empty or not.

For reference about save_post action:
[Plugin API/Action Reference/save post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)